# Skeletal tracker?

Tags: ros, openni, skeletal-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to use the skeletal tracker under openni_kinect and i noticed that it publishes translation and rotation values. But the rotation is represented by w,x,y,z; what do these represent? Also in case of translation, which variable represents depth, which one for height and which one for left-right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12833/skeletal-tracker?/) by [Kamal](https://answers.ros.org/users/740/kamal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rotation is represented as a quaternion which has values in a non-readable format. You can use tf to convert between quaternions and euler angles ( e.g. tf::Quaternion createQuaternionFromRPY(double roll,double pitch,double yaw) ).

What do you mean by height and left-right? What joint are you referring to?

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kamal](https://answers.ros.org/users/740/kamal/) on 2012-02-02**:
This helped... Thanks a lot !!

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-02-02**:
In Python you can e.g. use: euler_angles = euler_from_quaternion([x,y,z,w])  ... the angles are in rad. Check: http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/namespacetf_1_1transformations.html for the API

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-02-02**:
You can get the three axes by converting to euler angles using tf ... The euler angles represen the rotations around x,y and z axis.

**Comment by [Kamal](https://answers.ros.org/users/740/kamal/) on 2012-02-02**:
If camera is the origin, then what are the three axes directed along (for any joint) ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find the answers to your questions in [REP103 - Standard Units of Measure and Coordinate Conventions](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1